# Can i add internal links in adminhtml?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, link

i am writing an payment module but sadly it only supports one currency. i would like to add a message which currency is supported and provide and internal link to the currency setup setting on the admin site.
as if right now i'm not sure how to link to that section, is 'it even possible?

the link would be in the same place as the "more information" link in the amazon pay plugin, but it would take the administrator the "currency setup" portion of the interface
[image: the example i want to imitate]
[image: this is where i want the link to lead to]

Comment: Where you want to show this links?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya in the description of the module i'll add a picture of what i mean